# EFCore / EntityEntry / attaching

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm pretty new to EFCore and the change tracker, but I see we can extract EntityEntry from a context.  I've been searching, but I'm wondering if there is a shortcut to Attach an EntityEntry to another context.  If this is possible, the remaining step would be to compare the OriginalValues with those contained in the new context - if they are different, then SaveChanges should not fire for concurrency reasons - it could be as simply as comparing a timestamp or a hash value.

In short is there a way to Attach an EntityEntry to another context?

I realize that we could simply marshal the current values, but that's more code and effort than simply attaching the EntityEntry directly to a new context.

Answer (score -1):

So we used RIA Services, which then became OpenRIA - and the changes that are tracked in the EF Context on the client side are transported over to a EF Context on the server side.  We have reviewed the code of OpenRIA, and it's beyond this team to convert OpenRIA Service to dotnet 3.0 and use GRPC to emulate what it is currently doing.

As we want to ensure have a handle on our code base, we are working through what we can do to transport the EF Context changes to the server that serves our needs.

BTW - I should have noticed that EntityEntry was non serializable, and hence no way to transport.  Too bad nobody thought of raising that issue!